# With pysftp or Paramiko, how can I get a directory listing complete with attributes?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

As the title says, I'm trying to get a list of all the files and directories in a directory, including their attributes (I'm looking for at least name, size, last modified, and is it a file or a folder). I'm using Python 3 on Windows.

I've tried `listdir()`, and I get a list of files without attributes. I've tried `listdir_attr()`, and I get a list of attributes, but no filenames - and I don't see anything that guarantees that those two lists will be in the same order, so as far as I know, I can't just process the two lists together.

Even if I just end up with a big string that looks like a regular FTP / Linux `ls` listing, that's fine, I can parse that later. I just need anything that has each file or folder and at minimum the attributes I'm looking for for each.

Here's a sample program. The connection values are valid and can be used for testing, it's a public test SFTP server.

```
import pysftp

cnopts=pysftp.CnOpts()
# - I know this next line is insecure, it's just for this test program and
#    just to get a directory listing.
cnopts.hostkeys = None

print('Connecting...')
with pysftp.Connection('test.rebex.net', username='demo', password='password',
                    cnopts=cnopts) as SFTP:

    mydirlist = SFTP.??????
    #                ^^^^^^ What goes here?

print('Result:')
print(mydirlist)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pysftp [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) (as well as Paramiko [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr), which is behind it) returns everything.

If you directly print the list that the method returns, it does not print the names, due to the (wrong?) way its [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) is implemented.

But if you print individual elements, it prints the names (as [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) has better implementation):

```
files = sftp.listdir_attr(".")
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

To extract element's filename, read `SFTPAttributes.filename`:

```
files = sftp.listdir_attr(".")
for f in files:
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(f.st_mtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    print("{}: {} {}".format(f.filename, f.st_size, t))
```

Comment: This is PERFECT - works, is explained simply, and is worded nicely. This is absolutely perfect, thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Related: For anyone coming across this in the future, if you want the linux-style dir listing in a string, start with the code sample at the top, and replace

```
    mydirlist = SFTP.??????
    #                ^^^^^^ What goes here?
```

with this instead:

```
    mydirlist=""
    for i in SFTP.listdir_attr():
        mydirlist = mydirlist + str(i) + "\n"
    mydirlist = mydirlist.rstrip()
    print(mydirlist)
```

This took me some figuring out, figured I'd share if anyone needs it in the future.

Comment: Interesting! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you! Updated the code to reflect your suggestion. :-)