# Optimize the performance of retreiving file sizes with pysftp

Tags: python, python-3.6, sftp, pysftp

I have a requirement to get the file details for certain locations (within the system and SFTP) and get the file size for some locations on SFTP which can be achieved using the shared code.

```py
def getFileDetails(location: str):
    filenames: list = []
    if location.find(":") != -1:
        for file in glob.glob(location):
            filenames.append(getFileNameFromFilePath(file))
    else:
        with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword) as sftp:
            remote_files = [x.filename for x in sorted(sftp.listdir_attr(location), key=lambda f: f.st_mtime)]
            if location == LOCATION_SFTP_A:
              for filename in remote_files:
                filenames.append(filename)
                sftp_archive_d_size_mapping[filename] = sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size
            elif location == LOCATION_SFTP_B:
              for filename in remote_files:
                filenames.append(filename)
                sftp_archive_e_size_mapping[filename] = sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size      
            else:    
              for filename in remote_files:
                  filenames.append(filename)
            sftp.close()
    return filenames
```

There are more than *10000+* files in *LOCATION_SFTP_A* and *LOCATION_SFTP_B*. For each file, I need to get the file size. To get the size I am using

```py
sftp_archive_d_size_mapping[filename] = sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size
sftp_archive_e_size_mapping[filename] = sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size
# Time Taken : 5 min+
```

```py
sftp_archive_d_size_mapping[filename] = 1 #sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size
sftp_archive_e_size_mapping[filename] = 1 #sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size
# Time Taken : 20-30 s
```

If I comment `sftp.stat(location + "/" + filename).st_size` and assign static value It takes only 20-30 seconds to run the entire code. I am looking for a way How can optimize the time and get the file size details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) already gives you the file size in `SFTPAttributes.st_size`.

There's no need to call `Connection.stat` for each file to get the size (again).

See also:

- [With pysftp or Paramiko, how can I get a directory listing complete with attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58966394/850848)
- [How to fetch sizes of all SFTP files in a directory through Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51298467/850848)